# Logitech MX Master 3 - Bluetooth connection - Battery status

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, power-management, battery, logitech

I'm having issues getting the battery status of my *Logitech MX Master 3* mouse, **connected via Bluetooth**. I've seen many questions related to battery status on this mouse, and some fixes too, but they're all related to using the Unifying Receiver, and this is not my use case since I have an integrated Bluetooth receiver in my laptop and I paired the mouse directly.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and I paired the mouse by just finding and selecting it from the `Settings->Bluetooth` panel. I also installed *logiops* and enabled it as a service: it recognizes the mouse but it does not seem to change anything in its behaviour with the default settings: I feel like it performs better in scrolling, but it could be placebo.

So, it seems that everything is working perfectly out of the box. Unfortunately I can't use *solaar* to graphically configure it, but not a major issue. The only thing I can't do at all is displaying its battery status.

This is the relevant output from `upower --dump`:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/mouse_dev_F6_C7_A9_1C_FC_A1
  native-path:          /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F6_C7_A9_1C_FC_A1
  model:                MX Master 3
  serial:               F6:C7:A9:1C:FC:A1
  power supply:         no
  updated:              gio 1 gen 1970, 01:00:00 (1590657130 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  mouse
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        no
    state:               unknown
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          100%
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'
```

Thanks

Comment: one way to check if the settings are actually working is to tweak `smartshift: { on: true; threshold: 20; };`. Change 20 to something higher such as 130 and you should notice a change in the top button behavior. Another way would be to make the setting `{ cid: 0xc4; action = { type: "Keypress"; keys: ["BTN_BACK"];    }; }` which will cause the top button to act like the back button. If these don't result in any noticeable change then your settings are not getting loaded.